# Can polyglossia's option splithyphens be used in English?

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia, english

Croatian, Czech and Slovak languages in polyglossia have `splithyphens` as an option. It causes that, when a word with a hyphen is hyphenated at the hyphen, the original hyphen is at the start of the next line.

```
one-dimensional
→
one- (the hyphen added by hyphenation)
-dimensional (the original hyphen)
```

Can this or something similar be set in polyglossia for English text? I'd like to use that because it prevents loss of information if hyphenation occurs at a hyphen.

The option is described in sections 6.7, 6.8 and 6.36 of [the manual of polyglossia](https://mirrors.nic.cz/tex-archive/macros/unicodetex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf).

(Also, I'd like that the solution would enable hyphenating words with hyphens in English. It's disabled as far as I know. Without it, the solution would have no effect, and I want it because I get errors about overfull h-boxes from the lack of hyphenation of words with hyphens.)